# How do I change the color of Flutter NavBar() icon?

Tags: flutter

How do I change the color of the flutter navbar?
[how do I change the color of this icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7UIR.png)

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            drawer:  NavBar(),
        );
    }
}
```

This is my current code to show the navbar.

Can I change the color of the icon to blue for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the complete example that you can use in your app. you can test this code here (https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer) by replacing the code in the interactive example with the code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.menu,
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    size: 24.0,
                    semanticLabel: 'Text to announce in accessibility modes'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                });
          },
        ),
        title: const Text('Pink Menu Icon'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Understanding your question you need to update the icon of the drawer icon. The drawer icon is part of the app bar you can use the leading property of the app bar to update the icon shown. Here is the sample code for doing the same.

Docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer

Leading property of App Bar: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/leading.html

```
AppBar(
  leading: Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
        onPressed: () { Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); },
        tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: Hi Shekhar Suman Im new to flutter and I dont know where to add the style: colors function to change the icon color would it be inside icon: const Icon(Icons.menu) ?

Comment: @rabbiteatingmoney please find the complete code in my other answer. 
P.S: Welcome to flutter

Answer (score 0):

To add style to an IconButton you would do something like this.

```
IconButton(
              iconSize: 30, -> Changes the size
              icon: const Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.grey),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
```

Hope it helps.